# SharPoint People Picker

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Hello Is there any People Picker Service/Web Service in SharePoint 2013?  Actually i want to check some user existence in People Picker through PowerShell. I have a list of users in  csv file.

Comment: you can use the API. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteusers.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercollection.getbyemail.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following powershell to check a user exists in a group:

```
$w = get-spweb http://my
$gs = $w.SiteGroups
$g = $gs[12]
$user = $g.Users.GetByEmail("user@domain.com")
if($user -eq $null){write-host "User Not Found"}
```